# Pythonic way to access numpy array in reverse order

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to re-write some code that looks like it was written by a FORTRAN programmer to make it more Pythonic/readable. Below is the code snippet of interest. The overall behavior of the code is to store the first three elements of Z into Zstart so long as the values are less than 1, and also store the last three values of Z into Zend as long as they are less than 1 as well.

```
import numpy as np
nbpoints = 3
Z = np.linspace(0,1.0,10)
Zstart = np.ones(nbpoints)
Zend = np.ones(nbpoints)
Zpts = np.size(Z)
for j in range(nbpoints):
    if Z[j] < Zstart[j]:
       Zstart[j] = Z[j]
    if Z[Zpts - 1 - j] < Zend[nbpoints - 1 - j]:
        Zend[nbpoints - 1 - j] = Z[Zpts - 1 - j]
```

The counter moving access of Zstart and Zend from both ends is tripping me up a bit. My current solution is the following.

```
import numpy as np
nbpoints = 3
Z = np.linspace(0,1.0,10)
Zstart = np.ones(nbpoints)
Zend = np.ones(nbpoints)
Zpts = np.size(Z)
for j in range(nbpoints):
    if Z[j] < Zstart[j]:
       Zstart[j] = Z[j]
    if Z[-(j+1)] < Zend[-(j+1)]:
        Zend[-(j+1)] = Z[-(j+1)]
```

Sample output from this code is:

```
Z = [ 0.0 0.11111111  0.22222222  0.33333333  0.44444444  0.55555556 
0.66666667  0.77777778  0.88888889  1.0 ]

Zstart = [ 0.0 0.11111111  0.22222222]
Zend = [ 0.77777778  0.88888889  1.0 ]
```

My solution feels like I'm still just re-writing poorly written code e.g. rearranging chairs on the deck of the Titanic. Is there a more Pythonic way to perform this operation?

Comment: can you give an example of input and desired output?

Comment: @JulienSpronck I added sample output. The input is just the Z array. A one-dimensional numpy array that varies from 0 to 1. In the actual code it is passed in, but for the purposes of this snippet I just used the numpy linspace function to emulate input data.

Comment: @wandadars What happens if the starting values are > 1? Do you store only those that are <1, or none at all?

Comment: @BradSolomon In the context of the code that this snippet comes from, the values of Z are bound between 0 and 1. As for the initial values of Zstart and Zend, only the original author knows why they did that.

Comment: What?  If the values in Z are guaranteed to be 0 < value < 1, then why are you testing that they are <1 in the first place?

Comment: @BradSolomon I'm currently asking myself the same question. Original author is long gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate `Zstart` and `Zend` with `np.ones`.  Just build them directly:

```
nbpoints = 3
Z = np.linspace(0,1.0,10)
Zstart = Z[:nbpoints][Z[:nbpoints] < 1]
Zend = Z[-nbpoints:][Z[-nbpoints:] < 1]

print(Zstart)
print(Zend)
# [ 0.          0.11111111  0.22222222]    
# [ 0.77777778  0.88888889]
```

Notice that `Zend` has only 2 elements here, because the final element in `Z` is not less than 1.

Answer (score 1):

This code gives the same results without a moving counter

```
nbpoints = 3
Z=np.linspace(0,1.,10.)               
Zstart = np.ones(nbpoints)            
Zend = np.ones(nbpoints)              

Zstart[Z[:nbpoints] < 1] = Z[:nbpoints][Z[:nbpoints] < 1]  
Zend[Z[-nbpoints:] < 1] = Z[-nbpoints:][Z[-nbpoints:] < 1]
```